# Reverse engineering hardware serial interface, unexpected output in PuTTY

Tags: serial, hardware, reverse-engineering

I have a Chinese laser controller with a touch screen interface.  I've worked out that the touch screen is a standard off the shelf product communicating via RS422 with a custom control board.  I'm trying to snoop the serial commands going between the the control board and the screen so I can replace the touch screen with some PC software.

I've got a more or less working RS422 interface and can see something going between the screen and control board but it looks like it's not displaying correctly in PuTTY.  I wonder if the commands could be in Chinese characters rather than western? Is that a thing?

This is the output I'm getting:

[image]

There are two lines of errors displayed on the screen in English which correlate to the output in putty

1. 'Ver:260.COM3.V1.2
2. NO.03-Temperature is too high

When I hit buttons on the screen I get something new in putty but it looks like gibberish.  Anyone recognise the pattern of the non-sensical putty output or have any ideas of settings changes required to deal with non-western text?

I guess it could also be something like incorrect settings on the serial interface but given that the error message text strings are correct I think that's unlikely.

Needless to say, this comms interface is not documented anywhere.

Comment: why do you call that gibberish? ... the designers chose one unique character as a delimiter between data fields

Comment: I agree that your serial settings seem to be correct but don't understand why "PuTTY" appears on screen. You may need to examine the hex. Turn on Session | Logging | All and save the file. Then use a hex editor to examine the results.

Comment: please do not post a picture of text... copy the text and paste it into your question and format it as code ... that way it can be examined in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY is a terminal emulator. Therefore by default it responds to any terminal commands that are sent to it. The problem is if whatever the device sends are not supposed to be understood as terminal commands.

The protocol is likely binary so a text terminal emulator like PuTTY may not be the correct tool to analyze binary protocols.